# How to write/echo a log message when some event occurs using puppet?

Tags: puppet

For example, if I want print "Reboot required!" when the file /var/run/reboot-required exists, how could I declare this in puppet?

I learned about alert(), warning() and the notify type, but I don't know how to trigger they only when some file exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Facter to check if the file exists :

```
/etc/puppet/modules/mymodulename/lib/facter/reboot_require.rb

Facter.add("reboot_required") do
        setcode do
                File.exist?("/var/run/reboot-required")
        end
end
```

Then in your manifests, call the fact,

```
if ($::reboot_required == 'true') {
    notify {"Reboot Required":}
}
```

Comment: Actually it is not working for me... it is always echoing "Reboot Required, even when the file is not there. What could be happening?

Comment: see my edit. I have added `true` to the `if` condition. That might fix it.

Comment: That is it! Thanks! :-)  Just learned that puppet facts are always strings, that is so bad..